com.samsung.android.permission.RETURN_REMOTE_INPUT_VOICE has shown up on my Samsung phone and I would like to get rid of it
I found this on my phone and I would like to shut it down

com.samsung.android.permission.RETURN_REMOTE_INPUT_VOICE


Please edit your question and provide more details on how and where you encountered this permission.

I found this permission on my phone as well. I was looking at my battery usage and couldn't understand why the SAMSUNG KEYBOARD App was being so active in the background:

Despite having turned off background usage for that App:

Why does this App go through so much data and battery when I'm not using it? Why does it need to use mobile data anyway? So I checked the app permissions and amongst other ambiguous permissions that the user has no control of, such as take pictures and record videos when the app is in use (does that include background usage?) and download files without notifying the user, it also has this listed as a permission:
com.samsung.android.per mission.RETURN_REMOTE _INPUT_VOICE
When you click on an apps permission, it gives a pop-up window explaining the permission, which is useful for the user to understand what it does and why. But some permissions which have unusual titles like the one in question, the pop-up window has no information, just "OK".
